# Replacing text context in R

Tags: regex, r, str-replace

I have some text, on which I would like to detect all consecutive single-word characters and delete the spaces in between. However, punctuation should be respected. For example, if I have:

```
sampleText = "Abc defg h i j k, l mn, o p qrst."
```

I would like my result to be like this:

```
processedText = "Abc defg hijk, l mn, op qrst."
```

What is the best way to do this in R?

If I absolutely had to plan this now, I would probably:

1. `str_extract(sampleText, pattern = \\w(?: \\w)+)` (also remember the character position of each detection)
2. `str_replace(extractedText, " ", "")`
3. Insert the replaced text back in, using the indices from step 1, starting from the end and going backwards.

However, this sounds very inefficient to me. I am guessing that there is a way to do this without all this fuss, right?

Comment: How come a comma is removed if you plan to only remove spaces? Try `str_replace(sampleText, "(?<!\\S)(\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "\\1")` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lC0uN7/1))

Comment: Mistype, comma should be respected. Your suggested pattern produces `"Abc defg hi j k, l mn, o p qrst."`

Comment: Well, that is the difference between the ICU and PCRE engines. Use `gsub("(?<!\\S)(\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "\\1", sampleText, perl=TRUE)`. I get `[1] "Abc defg hijk, l mn, op qrst."`

Comment: This seems to be working great! (although I would prefer to stick to the stringr package) Please post this as an answer, so I can accept is as the correct solution. Could you please explain what the `"\\1"` part does? Alternatively, could you please post some link that explains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a PCRE-based regex with `gsub` from base R:

```
gsub("(?<!\\S)(\\w)\\s(?=\\w\\b)", "\\1", sampleText, perl=TRUE)
[1] "Abc defg hijk, l mn, op qrst."
```

The [regex demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/lC0uN7/1).

**Details**:

- `(?<!\\S)` - there should not be a non-whitespace char before...
- `(\\w)` - Group 1 capturing 1 word char (`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, replace with `[a-zA-Z]` to only match ASCII letters, or adjust as you need)
- `\\s` -  a whitespace
- `(?=\\w\\b)` - there must be a word char followed by a word boundary.

The `\1` in the replacement pattern just inserts the value captured into Group 1 
back to the resulting string.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much! I am not quite sure how the expression manages to capture multiple combinations without using the `*` or `+` quantifiers. My guess is, since you replace the captured group, the process continues recursively?

Comment: `gsub` matches multiple non-overlapping chunks of text in the input string, and replaces them with the replacement pattern. The `(?<!...)` and `(?=...)` are called *lookarounds* that do not consume text, that is, the regex index stays where it was and a check is done resulting in either *true* (go on) or *false* (fail the match). Thus, this expression matches any single word char and a whitespace, but checks the context with a lookbehind and a lookahead.

Comment: It is the first time I can do this! :)